# Excel List to Photoshop Layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, microsoft-excel

Is it possible to import an Excel file into Photoshop such that each item on a list has its own individual layer, with each layer located in the exact same place? E.g. there is a document with a blank for a name, a list of names in the Excel file, and the list is imported so that the names fill the blank when the layers are selected.

Other suggestions as to how to accomplish this are welcome.

Comment: You seem to be describing [Photoshop's  data driven graphics](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html#:~:text=Create%20data-driven%20graphics%201%20Rename%20a%20variable%20Choose,5%20Creating%20data%20sets%20in%20external%20files%20) functionality. It's a bit like mail merge but for Photoshop. If you want a tutorial there's [one here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6W9C61U5jgU) that goes through the process.

Comment: In an office suit this would be called mail merge. In Scribus it can be done, via the Scribus Generator ad-on. Why would you use Photoshop specifically? Do you have actual graphic effects happening on those list-items? Or could you generate a "background" in Photoshop and make the text-magic happen in some other tool? Maybe share a hand-made example with two different list-items.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.